# databricks pyspark connectivity to MongoDB Atlas not working

Tags: azure-databricks, mongodb-atlas, databricks-unity-catalog

i am using pyspark on databricks (cluster is unity enabled. ADB runtime=13.3) to connect to mongoDB Atlas.

i am using lib (latest version as per mongo document)=> org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:**10.2.1**

I am getting following error, although it is still reading table format correctly. check the bold part.

I was able to use older version of lib => org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:**3.0.1** but not the new one.

[UC_COMMAND_NOT_SUPPORTED.WITHOUT_RECOMMENDATION] The command(s): Data source v2 are not supported in Unity Catalog. ;
RelationV2[**Mindset shift#78, Starting mindset#79, _id#80, date#81, experience#82, games#83, postSurvey#84, preSurvey#85**]  MongoTable()